# Apply tap event for button in jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Could someone please suggest how I could apply a [tap event](http://api.jquerymobile.com/tap/) for the below html element.

```
<button class="btn btn-danger delete" data-type="DELETE" data-url="/upload/delete/2582">
         <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
         <span>Delete</span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$( ".btn.btn-danger.delete" ).bind( "tap", tapHandler );

function tapHandler( event ){
 //Rest code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".btn.btn-danger.delete").off('tap').on('tap', function(e){

// code

});
```